# Mongodb aggregation query $addFields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation

I got stuck in mongodb aggregation. I have a document like this in mongodb, we have details array in doc.

```
{
    user: "userName1",
    details: [{
        adminId: "admin123",
        id: "1",
        name: "name1",
        available: true,
        address: "address1"
    }, {
        adminId: "admin123",
        id: "2",
        name: "name2",
        available: false,
        address: "address2"
    }]
}
```

We need to compare below data with details in docs and add those are not available in details with aggregation

```
// this is the comparing data
data = [{
        adminId: "admin123",
        id: "1",
        name: "name1",
        address: "address1"
    },{
        adminId: "admin123",
        id: "2",
        name: "name2",
        address: "address2"
    },{
        adminId: "admin123",
        id: "3",
        name: "name3",
        address: "address3"
    },{
        adminId: "admin123",
        id: "4",
        name: "name4",
        address: "address4"
    }]
```

this is the expected response after aggregation

```
//expected response from database after aggregation
{
    user: "userName1",
    details: [{
        adminId: "admin123",
        id: "1",
        name: "name1",
        available: true,
        address: "address1"
    },{
        adminId: "admin123",
        id: "2",
        name: "name2",
        available: false,
        address: "address2"
    },{
        adminId: "admin123",
        id: "3",
        name: "name3",
        address: "address3"
    },{
        adminId: "admin123",
        id: "4",
        name: "name4",
        address: "address4"
    }]
}
```

Comment: do you want to perform update or aggregation

Comment: @AsZik Aggregation

Answer (score 0):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/9F8nM7LHbZn

you can use below aggregation where we first iterate through the data to compare and if we find data then take matched one otherwise we use the data to be compared.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
        "$addFields": {
            "data": [{
                    adminId: "admin123",
                    id: "1",
                    name: "name1",
                    address: "address1"
                },
                {
                    adminId: "admin123",
                    id: "2",
                    name: "name2",
                    address: "address2"
                },
                {
                    adminId: "admin123",
                    id: "3",
                    name: "name3",
                    address: "address3"
                },
                {
                    adminId: "admin123",
                    id: "4",
                    name: "name4",
                    address: "address4"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$data"
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "found": {
                $in: [
                    "$data.id",
                    "$details.id"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "details": {
                $cond: [{
                        $eq: [
                            true,
                            "$found"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        $first: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$details",
                                as: "data",
                                cond: {
                                    $eq: [
                                        "$$data.id",
                                        "$data.id"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "$data"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "details.id": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "user": {
                "$first": "$user"
            },
            details: {
                "$addToSet": "$details"
            }
        }
    }
])
```